# Deleting element from Binary Index Tree

Tags: c++

I have Binary Index Tree(BIT) which has stored distinct sorted values.
eg. query(1) returns 1, query(2) returns 2 and so on.

I want to find nth maximum element in this BIT. But that element should not be repeated next time. eg. Initially 4th maximum is 4. Next time 4th maximum will be 5, after that 4th maximum will be 6.

One way I thought about is to get nth maximum and then delete that element from BIT or left shift all elements right to that element by 1, so that it will not be repeated next time.
But I am not able to find out how to delete element or shift elements of BIT.

Can anybody tell how to do this if it is possible?

Comment: Have you made any attempts at making this delete function yet? Are you constrained to using a BIT or can you change the data structure?

Comment: I thought on delete function, but got absolutely no idea. I am not constrained to using BIT, but I want to know how to do this using BIT(if it is possible to do).

Comment: Also I want to do it in log(n) time

Comment: Maybe this would help? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/order-statistic-tree-using-fenwick-tree-bit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic BIT data structure looks something like this:

```
value 1|2|3|4|5|6   
f     1|0|2|1|1|3   
c     1|1|3|4|5|8   
tree  1|1|2|4|1|4
```

where:

> f[i] - frequency of value with index i, i = 1 .. MaxVal
>    c[i] - cumulative frequency for index i (f[1] + f[2] + ... + f[i])
>    tree[i] - sum of frequencies stored in BIT with index i

(the above is directly from this [article](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees)).

Looking at the above data structure, we can see that it is not possible to do a delete in O(log n) time.  Imagine that we want to delete the first element from the tree.  In order to do this, we would need to update f[0], c[0], and tree[0], to reflect that this element no longer exists in the tree.  Unfortunately, we also need to iterate through the rest of the c structure since it represents a cumulative sum. After setting c[0] to be 0, c[1] is no longer accurate, and must be updated, and c[2] is no longer accurate... up through c[n-1].

This will be a O(n) operation in the worst case, the worst case being the deletion of the first element in the tree.

I think it would be a smarter choice to use a different data structure.  BITs and other binary trees are really good for finding and adding elements efficiently, but are not as good at removing elements.  I would recommend using a priority queue instead.  Priority queues (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) Wikipedia article), normally use a min-heap as their underlying data structure, and guarantee O(log n) removal.